# Page title of biliography

Tags: bibliographies

In a paper I created, the name of the last section is also the page heading for the biliography at the end. How can I change this so that on the pages with references the page title is "Bibliography"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No-one knowns what you are doing but you. Thus please provide example code, preferably as a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is.